# Ubuntu network interfaces

Tags: networking, 20.04, kernel, network-manager, interface

So on my laptop I have two interfaces enp1s0 and wlp2s0 and if I want to use either one of them I have to run `ifconfig x down` on the other. For example if I don't do that to enp1s0, it shows that I'm connected to the wifi network but I don't get access to internet.
Here's my /etc/network/interfaces if it's of any help.

```
auto lo
auto lo iface lo inet
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
allow-hotplug wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
```

I had ubuntu 18.04 until I upgraded recently to 20.04

Comment: You should look into [Netplan](https://netplan.io/), as this is the preferred method to configure networks on Ubuntu.

Comment: Look at `ip route`. Read `man ip ip-route`.